# Qt Creator Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects - module is not installed

Tags: qt, qml, pyside

QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
"Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects" is not installed
I'm using QtCreator.

I have the following error. I'm using Pyside 6 and Qt 6.3.1 and Python 3.10
I tried to reinstall the whole qt maintenance tool and still nothing.
Can You guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should install this module separately from Maintenance Tool.[image]

Comment: I have done this Bro, still the same error shows up

Comment: Sorry then. I had this issue with C++. And I had just to install this module and add `QT += core5compat` to my .pro file.
Maybe try to look the reason on Pyside side. This is what I found after quick search:
https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/PYSIDE/issues/PYSIDE-1957?filter=allissues
https://forum.qt.io/topic/126280/import-qt5compat-with-pyside6-in-qml-file

Comment: @KacperJóźwik did you manage to solve this? still facing this issue in my side

Comment: @EmersonOliveira not really, I left this and I am waiting to update, maybe this will fix the issue, sorry :((